# civicrm report access

Tags: wordpress, civireport, 4.7, acl

I am trying to limit access to reports using acl/groups as mentioned in the userguide :

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.7/reporting/set-up/#define-report-settings

However, the field to set this does not appear. 
[image: access tab for report]

Is there something i have to configure to make this appear? Or does this functionality no longer exist?

If relevant I am already using acl for controlling access to custom data sets.

Running civicrm 4.7.17 on wordpress 4.7.3 using php 7.0.15

UPDATE 1:

looking through the code it seems that the following code (found in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form/instance.php) is causing it not to appear:

```
if (function_exists('user_roles')) {
        $user_roles_array = user_roles();
        foreach ($user_roles_array as $key => $value) {
          $user_roles[$value] = $value;
        }
        $grouprole = &$form->addElement('advmultiselect',
          'grouprole',
          ts('ACL Group/Role'),
          $user_roles,
          array(
            'size' => 5,
            'style' => 'width:240px',
            'class' => 'advmultiselect',
          )
        );
        $grouprole->setButtonAttributes('add', array('value' => ts('Add >>')));
        $grouprole->setButtonAttributes('remove', array('value' => ts('<< Remove')));
      }
```

For some reason the 'user_roles' function does not exist.

So when the below code is run (found in /wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%48/48E/48E22AAC%%Instance.tpl.php) the php returns nothing:

```
<tr class="crm-report-instanceForm-form-block-role">
        <td class="report-label" width="20%"><?php echo $this->_tpl_vars['form']['grouprole']['label']; ?>
</td>
        <td><?php echo ((is_array($_tmp=$this->_tpl_vars['form']['grouprole']['html'])) ? $this->_run_mod_handler('crmAddClass', true, $_tmp, 'huge') : smarty_modifier_crmAddClass($_tmp, 'huge')); ?>
</td>
      </tr>
```

UPDATE 2:

looking a little higher in instance.php it looks like this might not be for wordpress even though this section still runs:

```
if ($config->userFramework != 'Joomla' ||
      $config->userFramework != 'WordPress'
    )
```

still unsure of why 'grouprole' doesnt exist for the other code though:

```
<tr class="crm-report-instanceForm-form-block-role">
        <td class="report-label" width="20%"><?php echo $this->_tpl_vars['form']['grouprole']['label']; ?>
</td>
        <td><?php echo ((is_array($_tmp=$this->_tpl_vars['form']['grouprole']['html'])) ? $this->_run_mod_handler('crmAddClass', true, $_tmp, 'huge') : smarty_modifier_crmAddClass($_tmp, 'huge')); ?>
</td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: It shows on my 4.7.17 so the functionality still exists.  Not sure though why you're not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a CMS issue. I see those options available at [Drupal Demo](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/18?reset=1&output=criteria) but not at [WP Demo](http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Freport%2Finstance%2F26&reset=1&output=criteria)

Comment: doesnt show on joomla either. i find it hard to believe that its a drupal only feature

Answer (score 1):

A temporary fix

I have managed to make it appear by modifying the code, though this isnt an ideal solution as updating will probably remove the change.

By replacing this (in instance.php):

```
if (function_exists('user_roles')) {
        $user_roles_array = user_roles();
        foreach ($user_roles_array as $key => $value) {
          $user_roles[$value] = $value;
        } // also remove the ending if bracket
```

with this:

```
$lib = URE_Lib::get_instance();
        $lib->get_user_roles();
        $user_roles_array = $lib->get('roles');
        $count = 1;
        foreach ($user_roles_array as $key => $value) {
          $user_roles[$count] = $key ;
          $count++;
        }
```

the wordpress user roles appear allowing the reports to be restricted based on wordpress roles.

It would be nice to see a proper solution for this.